# Printar no terminal a soma de uma coluna em SQL sem erros

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pyqt-5, pyside

estou tentando printar uma soma de uma coluna de SQLITE no terminal para eu conseguir manipular esse valor na minha aplicação, porem ele retorna o valor como a foto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fica com esses [()] entre os valores, ja tentei da seguinte forma tentar printar sem isso :

```
        try:
            banco=sqlite3.connect('banco_de_valores.db')
            cursor=banco.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT SUM (valor) FROM dados ")
            dadoslidos2=cursor.fetchall()
            dadoslidos23 = str(dadoslidos2)
            print(dadoslidos23)
```

porem retorna a mesma coisa, tem alguma forma de eu conseguir manipular para sair apenas o valor sem parentes e colchetes? obrigado desde já

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está retornando um array de tuplas, para acessar o valor precisa acessar o primeiro elemento do array (que retorna uma tupla), em seguida acessar o primeiro elemento da tupla (que é o valor que você deseja)

```
print(dadoslidos23[0][0])
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara ajudou demais, fiz exatramente como voce disse e apareceu o resultado certinho.